# How to interpret the P numbers that fairseq generate produces?

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

Using fairseq-generate.py, with the transformer architecture, each translation produces a section like this:

```
Why is it rare to discover new marine mammal species?
S-0     Why is it rare to discover new marine mam@@ mal species ?
H-0     -0.0643349438905716     Pourquoi est-il rare de découvrir de nouvelles espèces de mammifères marins?
P-0     -0.0763 -0.1849 -0.0956 -0.0946 -0.0735 -0.1150 -0.1301 -0.0042 -0.0321 -0.0171 -0.0052 -0.0062 -0.0015
```

With [this explanation](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#evaluating-pre-trained-models):

> H is the hypothesis along with an average log-likelihood; and P is the positional score per token position, including the end-of-sentence marker

I'm wondering if it is reasonable to say a low (absolute) number in the P row means higher confidence in that particular word? E.g. does -0.07 for "Pourquoi" means it was happier about that than it was (-0.1849) for "est-il"? And the low -0.0015 at the end means it was really confident the sentence should end there.

Background: What I'm trying to work out is if I can use either the H number, or somehow to use the individual P numbers, to get a confidence measure in its translation. I've been analyzing a handful of translations against the H number and didn't notice much correspondence between it and my subjective opinion of translation quality. But I've a couple where I thought it was particularly poor - it had missed a bit of key information - and the final P number was a relatively high `-0.6099` and `-0.3091` (The final P number is `-0.11` or so on most of them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q: I'm wondering if it is reasonable to say a low (absolute) number in the P row means higher confidence in that particular word?

- Yes. As the docs says, "*P is the positional score per token position*". The score is actually the log probability, therefore the higher (i.e., the lower *absolute* number) the more "confident". The source-code may not be that easy to follow, but the scores are generated by the [`SequenceScorer`](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq/sequence_scorer.py), and there you can see that scores are normalized (which includes a `log` either if when you're using a [single model](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/4f618a758ccd6b1924508ccbfb32eaacc3ea11c5/fairseq/sequence_scorer.py#L69-L71) or an [ensemble](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/4f618a758ccd6b1924508ccbfb32eaacc3ea11c5/fairseq/sequence_scorer.py#L96-L98)). Moreover, when printing the scores, they [convert them from base *e* to 2](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/4f618a758ccd6b1924508ccbfb32eaacc3ea11c5/fairseq_cli/generate.py#L215-L221):

  ```py
  print('P-{}\t{}'.format(
      sample_id,
      ' '.join(map(
          lambda x: '{:.4f}'.format(x),
          # convert from base e to base 2
          hypo['positional_scores'].div_(math.log(2)).tolist(),
  ))
  ```

> Q: What I'm trying to work out is if I can use either the H number, or somehow to use the individual P numbers, to get a confidence measure in its translation.

- It turns out that the H value is simply the average of the P values, as you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/4f618a758ccd6b1924508ccbfb32eaacc3ea11c5/fairseq/sequence_scorer.py#L111):

  ```py
  score_i = avg_probs_i.sum() / tgt_len
  ```

  also [converted to base 2](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/4f618a758ccd6b1924508ccbfb32eaacc3ea11c5/fairseq_cli/generate.py#L210). You can check that in your example:

  ```py
  import numpy as np
  print(np.mean([-0.0763,-0.1849 ,-0.0956 ,-0.0946 ,-0.0735 ,-0.1150 ,-0.1301 ,-0.0042 ,-0.0321 ,-0.0171 ,-0.0052 ,-0.0062 ,-0.0015]))
  # >>> -0.06433076923076922
  ```

  Another measurement that is often used to assess the performance of a language model is [Perplexity](http://kom.aau.dk/%7Etb/kurser/HTKBook/node188_mn.html). And a good thing is that perplexity can be easily computed based on the P values, as shown in the [Language Model example](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/examples/language_model/README.md) of the fairseq repository:

  ```py
  # Compute perplexity for a sequence
  en_lm.score('Barack Obama is coming to Sydney and New Zealand')['positional_scores'].mean().neg().exp()
  # tensor(15.1474)
  ```

  I'm not an expert on NLP, so I can't really tell you which one you should use in your case.

Comment: Thanks - links into the source code is much appreciated.  By "(absolute) number" I had meant "ignore the minus sign, just look at magnitude"; so I think we are saying the same thing there.

Comment: @DarrenCook Sure. Perhaps I read it too fast. Sorry. I updated the answer accordingly.